# Logout for an app which having multiple storyboards swift 5 (Going back to root view controller)

Tags: ios, swift5, xcode11, rootviewcontroller, uiscenedelegate

How to go back to rootview controller in swift 5 where scenedelegate is available instead of Appdelegate

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
//        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let initialViewController =
                storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "first_page")
            self.window!.rootViewController = initialViewController
            self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```

this is my scenedelegate code need to dismiss/popback to my first page.

i am having the first page in 
**Main.storyboard** but my logout function is in another storyboard called **Home.storyboard**

tried

```
self.view.window?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

But not working i have only one navigation controller that is for the first viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
let viewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first!.rootViewController as! 
YourViewController
```

And then use this viewController

Comment: is it possible make my navigation controller as rootview controller?

Comment: I think you can try this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58084612/10842413

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use topController for dismiss/popback or present/push:

```
    if var topController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController  {
        while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
            topController = presentedViewController
        }
    }
```