# Swift : self.window?.rootViewController doesn't work in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, uinavigationcontroller, uiscenedelegate

I want to navigate to a certain screen when the user press on the push notification.
However, `self.window?.rootViewController` keeps on giving me error, which is `Thread 1: Swift runtime failure: force unwrapped a nil value`.

Now I have tried using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58084127/ios-13-swift-set-application-root-view-controller-programmatically-does-not). It did work; however, it requires me to delete the `SceneDelegate.swift` file along with other files, and I don't want to.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("userNotificationCenter didReceive")
        defer {
            completionHandler()
        }
        guard response.actionIdentifier == UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier else {
            return
        }

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let destinationVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyPage") as! PageViewController

        let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController

        navigationController.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: false)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
    }
```

Could anyone show me an alternative way to navigate to a certain when the user presses on the push notification? Thank you in advance.

Comment: use this ```UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController```

Comment: Don't take use windows or even `keyWindow`. If you are using scenes, you should get the `UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate?.window`.

Comment: @RajaKishan it works. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use keyWindow instead. Try this extension:

```
extension UIApplication
{
    static func getKeyWindow() -> UIWindow? {
        return shared
            .connectedScenes
            .flatMap { ($0 as? UIWindowScene)?.windows ?? [] }
            .first { $0.isKeyWindow }
    }
}
```

and then:

```
let navigationController = UIApplication.getKeyWindow()?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController

navigationController.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: false)

UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this;

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
```

Use keyWindow instead of window

Comment: This keyWindow is deprecated.